# How to use it in other classes when you change the properties of an instance in Java

Tags: java

I'm started studying Java this time.
I'm having fun learning it, but there are parts I don't understand, so I ask.

Below is the code I wrote.

```
public class Info {
    String name;
    String company;
    
    Info(String n, String c) {
        name = n;
        company = c; 
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + ". working at " + this.company;
    }
   
}

public class Info_C {
    String position;
    String dept;
    String name;
    String company; 
    
    Info_C(Info i, String p, String d) {
        name = i.name;
        company = i.company; 
        position = p;
        dept = d;
    }
    public void setInfo(Info i) {
        this.name = i.name;
        this.company = i.company;
    }
    public void setPosition(String p) {
        this.position = p;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + ". Working as a " +this.position + " in " + this.company + "'s " + this.dept;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var Pf_B = new Info("Bob","Apple");
        var Pf_J = new Info("James","Google");
        
        var TM = new Info_C(Pf_B, "Team Manager","Sales Team1");
        var AM = new Info_C(Pf_B, "Assistane Manager","HR Team");
        var RE = new Info_C(Pf_B, "Research Engineer","R&D Team");
        
        System.out.println(Pf_B); // Bob. working at Apple
        System.out.println(Pf_J); // James. working at Google
        System.out.println(TM);   // Bob. Working as a Team Manager in Apple's Sales Team1
        System.out.println(AM);   // Bob. Working as a Assistane Manager in Apple's HR Team
        System.out.println(RE);   // Bob. Working as a Research Engineer in Apple's R&D Team
        
        Pf_B.setName("Eric");
        Pf_B.setCompany("Samsung");
        AM.setPosition("Team Manager");
        RE.setInfo(Pf_J);
        
        System.out.println("=========================Changed==========================");
        
        System.out.println(Pf_B); // Eric. working at Samsung
        System.out.println(TM);   // Bob. Working as a Team Manager in Apple's Sales Team1 
                                  // Why Bob. Apple? Thought Eric. Samsung
        System.out.println(AM);   // Bob. Working as a Team Manager in Apple's HR Team
                                  // Same here
        System.out.println(RE);   // James. Working as a Research Engineer in Google's R&D Team
    }
}
```

When modifying the instance attribute of the Info class, is there any way to make it applied to the instance attribute of Info_C?

Tried a lot and searched hard, but failed.
perhaps, it's because of my poor English. 
I can't move on to the next chapter because of my curious. Any help would be appreciated.

+) I'm not even sure if the title is a good title for me, but I'd appreciate it if you let me know if it needs to be corrected.

Comment: Did you read about polymorphism? You should consider `Info_C` to extends `Info` class. Visit the following link: https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/polymorphism-in-java/?amp#referrer=https://www.google.com&csi=0

Comment: #Timor Inheritance was my first thought, but I gave up because I did not know whether to maintain the Info_C(info i, String p, String d) format when creating an Info_C instance while using inheritance.

 It seems that someone else wrote it the way I was looking for. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Inheritance wouldn't solve his problem. You should always prefer "composition over inheritance" where possible btw. alonkh2's answer should solve his problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are changing the name and company of the `Info` object, but that does not change said values in the `Info_C` object. To solve this problem, I would change your code to this -

```
public class Info {
    String name;
    String company;
    
    Info(String n, String c) {
        name = n;
        company = c; 
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + ". working at " + this.company;
    }
   
}

public class Info_C {
    String position;
    String dept;
    Info info; 
    
    Info_C(Info i, String p, String d) {
        position = p;
        dept = d;
        info = i;
    }
    public void setInfo(Info i) {
        info = i;
    }
    public void setPosition(String p) {
        this.position = p;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return info.name + ". Working as a " +this.position + " in " + info.company + "'s " + this.dept;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var Pf_B = new Info("Bob","Apple");
        var Pf_J = new Info("James","Google");
        
        var TM = new Info_C(Pf_B, "Team Manager","Sales Team1");
        var AM = new Info_C(Pf_B, "Assistane Manager","HR Team");
        var RE = new Info_C(Pf_B, "Research Engineer","R&D Team");
        
        System.out.println(Pf_B); // Bob. working at Apple
        System.out.println(Pf_J); // James. working at Google
        System.out.println(TM);   // Bob. Working as a Team Manager in Apple's Sales Team1
        System.out.println(AM);   // Bob. Working as a Assistane Manager in Apple's HR Team
        System.out.println(RE);   // Bob. Working as a Research Engineer in Apple's R&D Team
        
        Pf_B.setName("Eric");
        Pf_B.setCompany("Samsung");
        AM.setPosition("Team Manager");
        RE.setInfo(Pf_J);
        
        System.out.println("=========================Changed==========================");
        
        System.out.println(Pf_B); // Eric. working at Samsung
        System.out.println(TM);   // Bob. Working as a Team Manager in Apple's Sales Team1 
                                  // Why Bob. Apple? Thought Eric. Samsung
        System.out.println(AM);   // Bob. Working as a Team Manager in Apple's HR Team
                                  // Same here
        System.out.println(RE);   // James. Working as a Research Engineer in Google's R&D Team
    }
}
```

Please note that not setting your class' member variables to private is not ideal, and the access to them should be done using getters and setters only.

Comment: thank you! I didn't know i could write something like that.

Comment: I'll also keep in mind that i must use class' member variables to private. I knew it wasn't and deleted it lol...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```
public class Info_C extends Info
```

the base class, Info in this case will give its properties to the child class. you can call the constructor of the parent class with `super()`.

Also see: **https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inheritance.asp**

Comment: Inheritance was my first thought, but I gave up because I did not know whether to maintain the Info_C(info i, String p, String d) format when creating an Info_C instance while using inheritance.

Comment: It seems that someone else wrote it the way I was looking for. Thank you for your attention!